# Models not getting created outside of models.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-errors

My project hierarchy -

MyProject -> myapp -> MyPackage -> models.py .

In this models.py there is a class -

```
class Tagline(models.Model):  
        name = models.CharField(max_length=20)  
        tagline = models.CharField(max_length = 40)  
    class Meta:  
        app_label = 'myapp'
```

But when i try and access this table ( either through the admin or a normal view )  django throws me an error stating -
Table "myapp_tagline" doesn't exist .
What else besides the app_label do I have to specify in order to get django to detect this model.

P.S. Also how do I indent my code here?

Comment: For indentation, please use [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). A [Help link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) pops up when you try to edit/add a question as well.

Comment: Is this app included in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Have you run `syncdb` after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to be in `<app>.models`. Import it there.

`Meta` is a class attribute, so it has to be at the same indentation as the other class attributes.

Comment: Also in the init.py of this models sub-package file after entering this line -
from .mypackage import Tagline . It works. Thanks Ignacio. You saved the day again.